# Center an element which is "inline with text"

Tags: pages

In Pages it is possible to center an element (such as an image, a table, etc.) whose "Object Placement" has been made "Move with Text" and "Text Wrap" setting into "Inline with text"? When I click the image, table, or chart, I see no option in the format styles panel to center the element.

The only way I can see myself doing this is by adding spaces or tab characters before the image or table, but this doesn't seem like a nice way to do it (although it should be okay as long as the page size/margins stay constant). Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t want to use Text Wrap 'Around'?

Comment: It causes graphs to be cut off (instead of having them move entirely to the next page) when adding text above them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the text formatting for the paragraph containing the image rather than the image itself.

Click beside the image to move the insertion point to the paragraph, then use the format inspector to set the alignment.

[image]